# Java format date to three seperate fields into Elastic Search

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to parse a date into Elastic Search so I can create a Controls chart in Kibana based on the month, "week of the year" and "day of the week".

I created the index with the following call:

```
PUT periodically-active-users/

{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "userId": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "date_month": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "MMMM"
            },
            "date_week": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "w"
            },
            "date_day": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "dd"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I generate the inserts in java like this:

```
private static final String DATE_FORMATTER_MONTH = "MMMM";
private static final String DATE_FORMATTER_WEEK = "w";
private static final String DATE_FORMATTER_DAY = "dd";

String date_month = LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMATTER_MONTH));
String date_week = LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMATTER_WEEK));
String date_day = LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMATTER_DAY));

MonthlyActiveUsers monthlyActiveUsers = new MonthlyActiveUsers(1, date_month, date_week, date_day);
```

The MonthlyActiveUsers model class that gets send:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class MonthlyActiveUsers {
    int userId;
    String date_month;
    String date_week;
    String date_day;
}
```

When I send the object to Elastic Search, I get the following parsing exception:

```
400 Bad Request: [{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse field [date_month] of type [date] in document with id '1'. Preview of field's value: 'december'"}],"type":"mapper_p... (580 bytes)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't know how elasticsearch works. But maybe it's a locale problem? When I execute your code I get `Dezember` as result, you get `december` and perhaps that is not readable by elasticsearch?

Comment: It's because java prints the month name in your language. But my java language is english (which is default in Elastic) so I'm not sure if that triggers the problem